# LINQ Strange Execution - Inconsistantly Consistant?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delayed-execution

This **IS** a delayed execution problem. However, my issue stems from the fact that I cannot ascertain **WHY** this execution is delayed sometimes, and not other times.

Code:

```
IList<LineItem> freeFlatItems = new List<LineItem>();

if(QualifyFreeFlatShipping)
    freeFlatItems = lineItems.Where(l => l.FlatShippingRate != null).ToList();

decimal? freeFlatShippingTotal = freeFlatItems.Sum(l => l.FlatShippingRate);

var globalShippingPromos = _promoService.GetGlobalShippingPromos();
```

Problem:

This code is in production, and works as expected. I recently make changese *elsewhere* and found that this test was not working in our unit testing. When I step through this function the following happens:

1. Before reaching this code, I verified the input data. All items in `lineItems`. Each Item **has** as value for `.FlatShippingRate`
2. QualifyFreeFlatShipping is `true`
3. Code Execution reaches the linq statment on line 4 (`freeFlatItems = etc...`)
4. Value of `freeFlatItems` remains unchanged as execution continues to line 6 (`decimal? freeFlatShippingTotal = etc...`)
5. `.Sum` is executed across an empty list.
6. Upon reaching line 8 (`var globalShippingPromos = etc...`) the value of `freeFlatItems` finally updates to what it *should* be. However... sum was ran on the previous value, and my shipping total is incorrect.

The Question(s):

1. Why is this still being delayed? I thought `.ToList()` forced the execution of the linq to generate the `IList<T>`
2. Why does this behave differently in a consistant manner? (My Test always behaves this way, production works fine, this code in LinqPad works fine). And before you suggest it, I have validated my test is built up correctly. Both in the test code and in step one above by validating the input data in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

1.

There is no delayed execution here. The "Where" is forced by ToList(), and the "Sum" is evaluated immediately and stored in the decimal. The error has to be somewhere else

2.

When you evaluate the sum a second time after line 8, lets say with:

```
decimal? freeFlatShippingTotal2 = freeFlatItems.Sum(l => l.FlatShippingRate);
```

do you then get the correct value? So, freeFlatShippingTotal2 != freeFlatShippingTotal ?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for taking the time to answer. This question however is 2 months old, I unfortunately don't remember much about what happened. I think I re-factored some stuff and approached it completely different to get around this. I'll give you +1 for taking the time so long after though :)

Comment: I don't know how I found this question, but I did not realize it was so old ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue with delayed execution. But I can suggest a cleaner way for the code to be written.

```
decimal freeFlatShippingTotal = 0.0m;
if(QualifyFreeFlatShipping)
    freeFlatShippingTotal = lineItems.Sum(l => l.FlatShippingRate ?? 0.0m);
```